# SQL Server : Create user that can not login through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, privileges

Is it possible to create a login user in SQL Server that can login through any application, but not using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Comment: No. WIndows has no notion of application identity; permissions are tied to a user. If application X can use a login to access the database, so can Management Studio. Low-tech solutions that are easily circumvented are logon triggers that check the application name; more involved solutions are encrypting the data (or the login information) and embedding the encryption key in the application. All of these solutions can be circumvented by a sufficiently savvy end user, however (but it may be enough if you don't expect your users to be savvy).

Comment: Just an idea - set login default database to some nonexistent one (maybe you have to create and drop it on the way).

Comment: If this isn't an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) I don't know what is.

Comment: ok @SeanLange, let me explain exactly what I need. I have a team working on my application. They uses Visual Studio where I have my connection string in web config. I don't want my developers to connect to my production database using SSMS. But they should be able to debug scenarios in production in visual studio.
One more thing. I am using Azure SQL.
Logon trigger is not available in Azure SQL.

Comment: Ummmm......what???? You want direct production access to fix data but not direct production access. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You either trust your developers or you don't. If you indeed find some crude way of rejecting certain SQL clients (e.g. SSMS), then there are many, others SQL clients out there that the developers can (and will) switch to. As long as they have the username and password, there is nothing you can do to prevent (direct) access to the database.

Comment: The clean solution to this is to ensure your connection string / application role has only exactly the permissions it needs to, and then you shouldn't care whether the developers are accessing it through their debugged web service, or by directly composing queries (which they can, after all, always do simply by writing code in Visual Studio). If developers shouldn't be allowed to see the data at all except through the service, they have no business debugging it either. Set up a staging DB with anonymized data, or else introduce another data layer that allows only specific operations.